# Swift error while trying to implement a search bar

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a search bar into my code and for some reason I get the error, `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project`, This only happens when the if statement is implemented but works fine with the print statement. Is there a problem with If statements or am I using them wrong? The way I wanted it to work is to show all of the Core Data entries unless something is entered in the Search Bar(I presume using a or statement in the If statement to check if search == "") and if something is entered into the search bar only show the entries who's name attribute contains what the search bar shows. I am using Xcode 12.5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct customers: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Customer.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Customer.name, ascending: true)]) var customered: FetchedResults<Customer>


@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@State var search = String()
    
var body: some View {
    TextField("Search", text: $search)
    VStack{
        HStack{
            Text("Name")
        }
        Group{
            List(customered) {that in 
               if(that.name?.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())){
                Text(that.name ?? "unknown")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if(that.shown){
                            that.shown = false
                        }else{
                            for shownVar in customered{   
                                print(shownVar.name?.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Thinking back this also takes a long time to compile and load so is there a faster and better way because at one point it wouldn't build because it took too long and said to break up the code(This is a much shorter version of the actual code).

Comment: This is compiler for "You did something wrong, but I am confused and I am not sure exactly what is wrong". you should start by commenting sections out and  make sure you comment out balanced braces. Before I start commenting stuff out I always do a Re-Indent which can be found Editor: Structure: Re-Indent or with the shortcut Ctrl-I.
There isn't anyway for us to diagnose it without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, that error message has a very specific recommendation, and swift.org has a lot of readers, so following that recommendation is probably a really good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is "that.name" can be nil, and so the compiler cannot understand what to do. Try something like this to achive what you want:

```
                if search.isEmpty {
                    Text(that.name ?? "unknown")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // ....
                        }
                } else {
                    if ( (that.name ?? "").lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())) {
                        Text(that.name ?? "unknown")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                // ....
                            }
                    }
                }
```

EDIT:

For conciseness, you use something like this:

```
struct CustomersView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Customer.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Customer.name, ascending: true)]) var customered: FetchedResults<Customer>

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    @State var search = String()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $search)
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Name")
            }
            Group{
                List($customered, id: \.id) { $that in
                    if search.isEmpty {
                        TapableTextView(cust: $that)
                    } else {
                        if ( (that.name ?? "").lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())) {
                            TapableTextView(cust: $that)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    

struct TapableTextView: View {
    @Binding var cust: customer
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(cust.name ?? "unknown")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                    if(cust.shown){
                        cust.shown = false
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: I just noticed you are using Xcode 12.5, in that case, try something like this:

```
struct CustomersView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Customer.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Customer.name, ascending: true)]) var customered: FetchedResults<Customer>
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @State var search = String()
    
    private func tapableText(_ ndx: Int) -> some View {
        Text(customered[ndx].name ?? "unknown")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                if(customered[ndx].shown){
                    customered[ndx].shown = false
                }
                print( "tapped on " + (customered[ndx].name ?? "unknown") )
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $search)
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Name")
            }
            Group{
                List(customered.indices, id: \.self) { ndx in
                    if search.isEmpty {
                        tapableText(ndx)
                    } else {
                        if ( (customered[ndx].name ?? "").lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())) {
                            tapableText(ndx)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```